# Wordpress Ajax Checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress

How to update content of `Checkout Page` using `Ajax`  in `Wordpress`

Update the payment block content using `Ajax` in `WordPress` dynamically change in a checkout page depend on shipping postcode. it is my functionality to and check in blur event .

```
 jquery(document).ready(function(){
jquery("#billing_postcode").blur(function()
        {
            var pin=jQuery("#billing_postcode").val();
            jQuery.ajax({
                            url : MyAjax.ajaxurl,
                            type : 'post',
                            data : {
                            action : 'pincheck_ajax_submit',
                                     'pin' : pin
                            },
                            success : function( response ) 
                            {
                                 if(response == 1)
                                 {
                                    location.reload();
                                 }
                                 if(response == 2)
                                 {
                                    jQuery(".payment_method_cod").html("");
                                 }
                            }
                    }); 
        });
});
```

If response 1 then I need to update enable COD and html content then what i can do?

Comment: Do you want to update it using Ajax or you have this functionality and its not working ? Please be specific.

Comment: your question is a way to general. What have you tried so far?

Comment: It is a general question to update check out page using ajax. I am new in wordpress. Anybody can give the Answer?